# Change scala code in databricks to send grouped data based on email

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a table of Records which is firstly collected here:

```scala
val finalResults: Array[Records] = 
  sqlContext.sql("select * from Records").as[Records].collect()
```

I then loop through these as the Records contain an email and I want to email only recipients their own data:

```scala
for(i <- 0 until finalResults.length){
  val email = finalResults(i).email
  val arrayOfRecords : Array[Records] =  Array(finalResults(i))
  val HTMLTableOfRecords: String = generateReport(arrayOfRecords)
     
  var emailContent : String = "";
  emailContent = s"""<html><head></head><body>
                     <p><h1>TITLE</h1></p>
                     <b>Here are your results:</b><br>
                        ${HTMLTableOfRecords}
                        <br><br>
                     </p>
                     <p>
                     </p>"""
      
  sendEmail(s"EXAMPLE RECORDS",emailContent, List(email))
}
```

Issue with this is that recipients data can appear more than once, so email can be `example@email.com` up to 4 times at least. The above code would send 4 separate emails to `example@email.com` if it appeared 4x in Records.

Question is how can I change the above code to be more smart and send out data for `example@email.com` in one email with the 3x records within that one email?

Edit:

I've updated the Records in the sql to be `order by email desc`. Just need a good way to have a check in place where if the emails are the same group them together along with the data in the Array then `generateReport`. Then move on to the next set of records after the index of the last email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to sort in sql, you can use `groupBy` in scala to group your records by email address:

```scala
finalResults.groupBy(_.email).foreach { case (email, arrayOfRecords) =>
  val HTMLTableOfRecords: String = generateReport(arrayOfRecords)
  // emailContent...
  sendEmail(s"EXAMPLE RECORDS",emailContent, List(email))
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how will this allow the data dependent on email to be grouped so I can send say example1@email.com his collected data and example2@email.com his data?

Comment: The `arrayOfRecords` contains all records for one email address. I have updated my answer to make it a bit clearer what you can do with it afterwards.

Comment: ahh I see so theres no need for the loop either then?

Comment: No, what you did with the loop, I did with the `foreach`